# Authentication Vulnerability Issue with Page Redirect

Tags: apex, security, pagereference, redirect

We are using a third party company to scan our salesforce code for SOQL Injection and Vulnerability issues with open page redirects. The below code is flagged as a vulnerability.

```
public Pagereference customCancel() {
    Pagereference objPageref = new Pagereference('/apex/FulcrumInlineEdit?id='+OptyId);
    objPageref.setRedirect(true);
    return objPageref;
}
```

The page is not using any URL hacking mechanisms like saveUrl, retUrl or cancelUrl. Based on the information given in the trailhead [Prevent Open Redirects in your code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_application_logic_vulnerabilities/secdev_app_logic_preventing_open_redirect), I am not sure how to modify the above code to make it secure. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

While I'd say the vulnerability tool is being overly-cautious here, it may be expecting you to construct the URL piecemeal, like so:

```
public PageReference customCancel() {
    PageReference objPageref = Page.FulcrumInlineEdit;
    objPageref.getParameters().put('id', OptyId);
    objPageref.setRedirect(true);
    return objPageref;
}
```

It's also likely that `OptyId` is of type `String` when ideally it should be of type `Id` (I'm assuming by the name that it's an Opportunity record Id), which would ensure nothing malicious could potentially be passed in.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will try this. And yes, OptyId is of type Id and it is the Opportunity Record Id.